# How do I reduce the amount of storage my Email application data is taking up?

Tags: internal-storage, email, storage

I’m using an LG Tribute phone (Virgin Mobile service).  The default email app installed is synced with my Microsoft Outlook account.  I only use this account for ticket confirmations, boarding passes and the like.  However, recently I noticed it is taking up the following storage:

```
Total: 635 MB
App: 24.5 MB
App (SD Card): 0 MB
Data: 610 MB
Data (SD Card): 0 MB
```

Considering my phone only has 2 GB of storage, the above is a heavy price to pay.  When I hit the “Clear Data” button, I get the message “All this app’s data will be deleted permanently.  This includes all files, settings, accounts, databases, etc.”  I don’t want to delete my account so I was wondering if there is any other way to slim down how much data my Email application is using?

Comment: You could try to lower the # of days that the app keeps synced (i.e. downloaded on the phone). Try to find if there is such an option in the app settings

Comment: Would that prevent my receiving emails immediately?

Comment: No, it means the app should keep only the last n days of mails on the internal storage. You will receive new mails as always

Comment: I chagned the setting from 3 days to 1 day but my data is still showing over 600 MB.  There is absolutely no way I have over 600 MB of email accumulated in one day so I assume this is not the way to adjust the data limit.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,
I am using LG nexus. Encountered same problem and concern with yours. Here is what I discover then did: tap "Settings"-"Storage"-"Photos&videos"-"Images"(I've chosen "Photos" app to open images always)-"Assistant"-"Empty your trash-bin". In this last step, you will see some other options that the "Assistant" provided. Choose accordingly.
Have a blessed day!

Answer (score 0):

when you delete the *app data* it will delete the account stored on that app data from the smartphone memory only, not the email account from the cloud.

So, you could just clear the data and re-run the app. It should automatically detect the email you configured for android OS  (that is auto used by all apps).

Or you can uninstall/disable the app and re-install/enable it, may work too.

What you will DO lose is any other settings you may have made like dark theme, etc. But these are usually easy to set again, if not, just take screenshots.

But, if you want to not risk anything, find a very light email app alternative. It will auto detect email account. Let it sync and compare sizes. If you like it, keep and disable the other. Otherwise, clear the other data, setup it again, and uninstall the new email app.

Ps.: i dont have your device model, this is just my general knowledge